# Retrieve data from a JsonP proxy in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am trying to get the data from a JSONP proxy in sencha touch 2.3(I am using sencha architect 3 to develop). I was successfully able to place jsonp call and get the data back. But I am not getting how to separate every single element of json response. Here is my json Response:-

```
{"data":[{   "PLANTNUM": "1557",   "ROUTEID": "90625",   "DELIVERYDATE": "2014-02-12T00:00:00-06:00",   "MESCOD": "15",   "MESFCT": "DLV",   "ORIGID": "HH",      "JMSTIME": "02/11/2014 00:11:21",   }],"success" : true}
```

Here is my function

```
 success: function(response){
console.log(response);
    var temp=response.data.PLANTNUM;
    console.log(temp);
}
```

I can see below in my console:-

[image: console]

Here is my jsonP request

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
url: 'http://localhost:12608',
callbackKey: 'cbfn',
params: {
    method: 'sapout',
    type: 'sap', 
    ordnum: '1034986850'
}
```

I tried using response.PLANTNUM but that is also not working. It always shows undefined
Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is an array, so you want `response.data[0].PLATINUM`.

Comment: Oops..missed that...Thanks a lot